# /etc/init.d/functions and action in centos and debian

Tags: bash, action

In centos.

```
source  /etc/init.d/functions
action "work done"  /bin/true
action  "wrong"  /bin/false
```

It show as below.

```
work done   [OK]
wrong       [FAILED]
```

I found that no `/etc/init.d/functions` in debian ,how to use `action "work done"  /bin/true` then?
Copy the file `/etc/init.d/functions` in centos into usb,and copy the file `/etc/init.d/functions` from usb into my debian?

Comment: What is `action`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably copy that script over but there might be some files and binaries that the script is using that are only available in CentOS. If you only need the fancy output of the function `action()`, here is a minimal script for that.

```
success() {
  echo -en "\\033[60G[\\033[1;32m  OK  \\033[0;39m]\r"
  return 0
}

failure() {
  local rc=$?
  echo -en "\\033[60G[\\033[1;31mFAILED\\033[0;39m]\r"
  [ -x /bin/plymouth ] && /bin/plymouth --details
  return $rc
}

action() {
  local STRING=$1
  echo -n "$STRING "
  shift
  "$@" && success $"$STRING" || failure $"$STRING"
  local rc=$?
  echo
  return $rc
}
```

Note however that the original `functions` script does more by checking the type of console and other stuff.